# How do you pass a void * back and forth to a shared library in python using ctypes?

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I believe the basic process is:

```
from ctypes import *

LEAP = ctypes.CDLL('leap.dylib')

leap_controller = LEAP.leap_controller
leap_controller.res_type = c_void_p

leap_controller_dispose = LEAP.leap_controller_dispose
leap_controller_dispose.argtype = [c_void_p]
```

However, when I invoke this code it mangles the void * pointer. Debugging from the associated C code, I get:

```
doug:test doug$ python test.py
Controller init!
returning: 0x7fcf9a0022c0
Created controller

Controller dispose!
argument: 0xffffffff9a0022c0
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Obviously the free() call fails because the pointer isn't right.

I've tried a couple of variations on this, for example, defining a structure, like:

```
class LEAP_CONTROLLER(Structure):
  _fields_ = [
      ("data", c_void_p)
  ]

leap_controller = LEAP.leap_controller
leap_controller.res_type = POINTER(LEAP_CONTROLLER)

leap_controller_dispose = LEAP.leap_controller_dispose
leap_controller_dispose.argtype = [POINTER(LEAP_CONTROLLER)]
```

...but the result always seems to be the same.

Python reads the pointer, but only keeps 32 bits worth of data, and returns a broken pointer with the remaining bits all 1.

Both of the binaries are 64 bit:

```
Non-fat file: /usr/local/bin/python is architecture: x86_64
Non-fat file: ../../dll/libcleap.dylib is architecture: x86_64
```

I saw this ancient issue, here:
http://bugs.python.org/issue1703286

...but it's marked as resolved.

A few other random mailing this threads seem to mention ctypes 'truncating 64-bit pointers to 32-bit', but people all seem to have magically resolved their issues without doing anything ('it works now') or gotten no answer to their questions.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Per the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes#specifying-the-required-argument-types-function-prototypes), it's `argtypes` and `restype`, not `argtype` and `res_type`.

Comment: @eryksun you're completely right (and yes, that wasn't a typo in my typing my question, it was a typo in my code); fixing it made it work. If you flick that up as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: ouch. A mistyped field name and no compiler to catch it, just silence.

Comment: @CharlieBurns: You could use a function prototype instead: `CFUNCTYPE(None, c_void_p)(('leap_controller_dispose', LEAP))`. Or to get an `AttributeError`, you could subclass [`CDLL`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ab05e7dd2788/Lib/ctypes/__init__.py#l332) to add `__slots__ = ['__name__', '__weakref__']` to the `_FuncPtr` class. This eliminates the instance dict. [`argtypes` and `restype`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ab05e7dd2788/Modules/_ctypes/_ctypes.c#l3125) are descriptors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer as per the comments; this was a typo in my code.

```
 Per the docs, it's argtypes and restype, not argtype and res_type. –  eryksun Oct 4 at 2:31
```